LINQ Dynamic Expressions with Generic Types
I'm attempting at creating a one stop "filter manager" for basic filtering...
so I have a filter object like so:
    public record DataTableFilter
    {
        public string? ColumnProperty { get; set; }

        public object? ColumnValue { get; set; }

        public string? Operator { get; set; }

        public ExpressionType FilterOperator
        {
            get
            {
                switch (Operator)
                {
                    case "=": return ExpressionType.Equal;
                    case "!=": return ExpressionType.NotEqual;
                    case ">": return ExpressionType.GreaterThan;
                    case ">=": return ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual;
                    case "<": return ExpressionType.LessThan;
                    case "<=": return ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual;
                    case "is empty": return ExpressionType.IsTrue;
                    case "is not empty": return ExpressionType.IsFalse;
                    default: return ExpressionType.Throw;
                }
            }
        }
    } 

Then I have an IQueryable extension method like so:
public static IQueryable<TSource> Compare<TSource, TValue>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector,
        TValue value,
        ExpressionType comparison)
{
    Expression left = selector.Body;
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue));

    BinaryExpression body;
    switch (comparison)
    {
        case ExpressionType.LessThan:
            body = Expression.LessThan(left, right);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
            body = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Equal:
            body = Expression.Equal(left, right);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
            body = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
            body = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException(nameof(comparison));
    }

    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, selector.Parameters));
}

Then I want to be able to do something like this:
var fm = new FilterManager();

var records = new List<SomeClass>();
records.Add(new SomeClass() { StringField = "sd", StringIdField = "01", Abbr = "A", Year = 2024 });
records.Add(new SomeClass() { StringField = "sd", StringIdField = "01", Abbr = "A", Year = 2023 });
records.Add(new SomeClass() { StringField = "sd", StringIdField = "01", Abbr = "A", Year = 2022 });
records.Add(new SomeClass() { StringField = "sd", StringIdField = "01", Abbr = "A", Year = 2021 });

var filters = new List<DataTableFilter>();
filters.Add(new DataTableFilter() { ColumnProperty = "Year", ColumnValue = 2024, Operator = "=" });

var filteredRecords = fm.Filter(filters, records.AsEnumerable()).Result.ToList();

Assert.IsNotNull(filteredRecords);
Assert.IsTrue(filteredRecords.Count() == 1);

Right now, my asserts are failing because the the filteredRecords is always returning a 0 count... Something about the left expression I feel is wrong... but I can't quite figure it out.
Full context... the IQueryable extension was lifted from a previous SO question, but I appear to have lost the link as of right now.
EDIT
Usage.. how forgetful of me..
        public Task<IEnumerable<T>> Filter<T>(IList<DataTableFilter> filters, IEnumerable<T> filterables)
        {
            if (filters == null || filters.Count() == 0)
                return Task.FromResult(filterables);

            var queryable = filterables.AsQueryable();
            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
#pragma warning disable CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
#pragma warning disable CS8604 // Possible null reference argument.
                queryable = queryable.Compare(x => 
                    x.GetType().GetProperty(filter.ColumnProperty).GetValue(x), 
                    filter.ColumnValue, 
                    filter.FilterOperator);

#pragma warning restore CS8604 // Possible null reference argument.
#pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
            }

            return Task.FromResult(queryable.AsEnumerable());
        }


    }


Am I missing something? Where are you using the Compare method that you wrote? The last code snippet doesn't seem to use it, unless I'm blind :)

@Sweeper not blind... I'm forgetful. I've made an edit for it's usage.

Is there a specific Reason why the Filter Method uses Tasks?
Do you want this to be awaitable at a later point?

Ok so as a little interim report: The issue seems to be the conversion.
if we break down the selector the right expression (rewritten to be readable)
would be something like ((object)x.Year). So the Where expression at the end if we fill in the gaps is
source.Where(x => ((object)x.Year == (object)2024)).
Now at first this looks fine buuuuuut if we do a little test
bool isEqual = (object)records[0].Year == (object)2024;
We will see that we get a false. So the issue as far as I can tell seems to be the object conversions. Im not quite sure how to go around that yet.

might i recommend either dynamic linq library OR suneelsarraf answer to this question
I think the latter especially since its very close to your example usecase whilst dropping some classes

Also and sorry for the many comments: will this only be needed for some basic properties like string ints and bools etc, or will this also be used on objects?

For the time being I recommend you simplu use suneelsarraf excelent answer to this question
This means we drop your Compare Method and take his Extensions
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> strToFunc<T>(string propName, string opr, string value, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = null)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> func = null;
        try
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var prop = type.GetProperty(propName);
            ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            Expression left = Expression.Property(tpe, prop);
            Expression right = Expression.Convert(ToExprConstant(prop, value), prop.PropertyType);
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> innerExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(ApplyFilter(opr, left, right), tpe);
            if (expr != null)
                innerExpr = innerExpr.And(expr);
            func = innerExpr;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return func;
    }
    private static Expression ToExprConstant(PropertyInfo prop, string value)
    {
        object val = null;

        try
        {
            switch (prop.Name)
            {
                case "System.Guid":
                    val = Guid.NewGuid();
                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        val = Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return Expression.Constant(val);
    }
    private static BinaryExpression ApplyFilter(string opr, Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        BinaryExpression InnerLambda = null;
        switch (opr)
        {
            case "==":
            case "=":
                InnerLambda = Expression.Equal(left, right);
                break;
            case "<":
                InnerLambda = Expression.LessThan(left, right);
                break;
            case ">":
                InnerLambda = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
                break;
            case ">=":
                InnerLambda = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);
                break;
            case "<=":
                InnerLambda = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);
                break;
            case "!=":
                InnerLambda = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
                break;
            case "&&":
                InnerLambda = Expression.And(left, right);
                break;
            case "||":
                InnerLambda = Expression.Or(left, right);
                break;
        }
        return InnerLambda;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> And<T, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Func<T, TResult> ExpressionToFunc<T, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expr)
    {
        var res = expr.Compile();
        return res;
    }
}

Now to get this in tune with your code we simply change Filter around a bit
    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> Filter<T>(IList<DataTableFilter> filters, IEnumerable<T> filterables)
    {
        if (filters == null || filters.Count() == 0)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(filterables);
        }

        var queryable = filterables.AsQueryable();

        foreach (DataTableFilter filter in filters)
        {
            var func = Extensions.strToFunc<T>(filter.ColumnProperty, filter.Operator, filter.ColumnValue.ToString());
            queryable = queryable.Where(func.ExpressionToFunc()).AsQueryable();
        }

        return Task.FromResult(queryable.AsEnumerable());
    }

and this should do it.
Now if you wanna use actual Object Properties to compare to instead of strings or ints then this approach would need some editing
